# Python file i/0: error -- How to write to a file when the filename given is a string?

Tags: python-3.x, io, fwrite

I have a function that accepts d (dictionary that must be sorted asciibetically by key,) and filename (file that may or may not exist.) I have to have exact format written to this file and the function must return None.

> Format: 
>   Every   key-value   pair    of  the dictionary  should  be  output  as: a   string  that    starts  with    key,    followed    by  ":",    a   tab, then   the integers    from    the value   list.       Every   integer should  be  followed    by  a   "," and a   tab except  for the very    last    one,    which should    be  followed    by  a   newline.

The issue is when I go to close the file and run my testers, it tells me this error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Obviously that means my file isn't a file, it's a string. How do I fix this?

Here is my current functions that work together to accept the dictionary, sort the dictionary, open/create file for writing, write the dictionary to the file in specified format that can be read as a string, and then close the file:

```
def format_item(key,value):
    return key+ ":\t"+",\t".join(str(x) for x in value)
def format_dict(d):
    return sorted(format_item(key,value) for key, value in d.items())
def store(d,filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f: 
        f.write("\n".join(format(dict(d))))
    filename.close()
    return None
```

Example of expected output:

> IN:   d    =   {'orange':[1,3],'apple':[2]}"
>   OUT: store(d,"out.txt") 
>   the file    contents should be  read    as  this    string: "apple:\t2\norange:\t1,\t3\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually set the file handle to f but you are trying to close filename.

so your close command should be f.close()

Comment: Thank you! That allowed me to close it.